# chrome.processes.getProcessIdForTab returns wrong pid

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my background page I have the following:

```
 chrome.processes.getProcessIdForTab(tabId, function(pid){
     console.log('proccess id is ',pid); 
 }
```

this return the number 8, which does not correspond with the process id I see in the windows task manager. 
does anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out alone, the pid returned from "getProcessIdForTab" is an internal chrome pid, to get the os process id you need to use "getProcessInfo" with the internal pid.